# How to store multiple record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My requirement is I want to store contact name corresponding to their `phone_no` but when I am using the `foreach` loop after explode the variable

`foreach($phone_no11 as $phone_nos)`

`foreach($contact_name11 as $contact_names)`

Then for every name all the phone number is storing so if my `phone_no` is 999,888,777 and `contact_name` is Watch,Sun,Sky then it store in database is

> Watch 999 Watch 888 Watch 777 Sun 999 Sun 888 Sun 777 Sky 999 Sky 888
>   Sky 777

please help me

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['phone_no'])&& isset($_GET['contact_name'])) { 
    include("connection.php"); 
    $phone_no1 = $_GET['phone_no']; 
    $phone_no11 = (explode(",",$phone_no1)); 
    $contact_name1 = $_GET['contact_name']; 
    $contact_name11 = (explode(",",$contact_name1));     // Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members" 
    foreach($phone_no11 as $phone_nos) 
    foreach($contact_name11 as $contact_names) 
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phone_directory (contact_name,contact_number) VALUES ('$contact_names','$phone_nos')"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: cannot help you unless you post some code you have

Comment: Clarify your question, post some exapmle code or show us more complex example.

Comment: <?php if(isset($_GET['phone_no'])&& isset($_GET['contact_name']))
{
include("connection.php");
$phone_no1 = $_GET['phone_no'];
$phone_no11 = (explode(",",$phone_no1));
$contact_name1 = $_GET['contact_name'];
$contact_name11 = (explode(",",$contact_name1)); 
// Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members"  
foreach($phone_no11 as $phone_nos)
foreach($contact_name11 as $contact_names)
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `phone_directory` (`contact_name`,`contact_number`)  VALUES ('$contact_names','$phone_nos')"); 
}
?>   this is my code

Comment: @AmbrishPratapSingh So, having `$_GET['phone_no']` as "999,888,777" and `$_GET['contact_name']` as "Watch,Sun,Sky"... What exactly do you want to store in the database?

Comment: @AmbrishPratapSingh, look at the answer below. I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
if(isset($_GET['phone_no'])&& isset($_GET['contact_name'])) { 
include("connection.php"); 
$phone_no1 = $_GET['phone_no']; 
$phone_no11 = (explode(",",$phone_no1)); 
$contact_name1 = $_GET['contact_name']; 
$contact_name11 = (explode(",",$contact_name1));     // Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members" 

$total_records = count($phone_no11);

for($i=0;$i<$total_records;$i++)
{
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phone_directory (contact_name,contact_number) VALUES ('$contact_name11[$i]','$phone_no11[$i]')");
} 

}
```

So first calculate, how many phone numbers or contact numbers you have (total_records), and then through loop insert them.

If you have a lot of records then putting mysql query inside loop is not a good practice. Batch query works perfect then.

Something like

```
 if(isset($_GET['phone_no'])&& isset($_GET['contact_name'])) { 
include("connection.php"); 
$phone_no1 = $_GET['phone_no']; 
$phone_no11 = (explode(",",$phone_no1)); 
$contact_name1 = $_GET['contact_name']; 
$contact_name11 = (explode(",",$contact_name1));     // Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members" 

$total_records = count($phone_no11);

$records = '';

for($i=0;$i<$total_records;$i++)
{
   $records .= ",('$contact_name11[$i]','$phone_no11[$i]')";
} 

 $records = sunstr($records,1);
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phone_directory (contact_name,contact_number) VALUES $records;

}
```

This is will first make batch query, and then run it out of loop.

Comment: You have an extra "count" in `count($total_records)` since you already did it in `$total_records = count($phone_no11)`

Comment: @Daniel, thanks. Just corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but one improvement needed here in the for loop in place of count($total_records) only $total_records needed because we have already counted it.

Comment: Yes, i have already changed it.  Daniel corrected it.

Comment: Don't forget to check `tick mark` for my answer :P